# $httpBackend.flush() throws error if the GET request is cached

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to test that my service is using cached GET requests.

Dumbed down version of the test:

```
  var url = "/test";
  var whenTestRequest = $httpBackend.when('GET', url);

  whenTestRequest.respond(200, "r1");
  $http({ url: url, method: 'GET', cache: true }).success(function (value) {
    expect(value).toBe("r1");
  });
  $httpBackend.flush();

  whenTestRequest.respond(200, "r2");
  $http({ url: url, method: 'GET', cache: true }).success(function (value) {
    expect(value).toBe("r1");
  });
  $httpBackend.flush();
```

I require the second `$httpBackend.flush()` so that my second `success` function gets called, but that second call to `flush` throws:

> Error: No pending request to flush !

So I need to wrap `flush` in the `try`/`catch`. That works, but is there a correct way of handling this?

Comment: Another approach would be to switch to using `$httpBackend.expectGET()` instead of `$httpBackend.when()`. The reason is that the "expect" version is more strict, and you can test that only one HTTP request is ever made. This approach changes your test significantly. Frankly, I never use the "when" functions b/c in my tests I want to assert that HTTP requests are made in the order/quantity that I expect.

Comment: This just bit me too... we can't be the first two to have run into this, can we?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to this - instead of calling `$httpBackend.flush()`, call `$rootScope.$digest()`. That's what the `flush` ends up doing in the background, except without checking for whether there are any requests pending, and it causes the promise for $http requests that are satisfied by the cache to be resolved.

I ran into this when I switched a project of mine to store directive templates in the template cache instead of doing http requests for each one. My old test created the directive like so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.expectGET('login.html').respond('<div></div>');
  $compile('<login-page/>')($rootScope);
  $httpBackend.flush();
}));
```

However, when I switched the tests to use the templates, the flush threw that exception, as the request was satisfied by the cache and never went on the virtual wire. But even after removing the $httpBackend stuff, the directive still wasn't getting built, because the `templateUrl` caused the whole directive init process to be in the `then` call of the promise for the request for the template. Even though the cache would satisfy the template request, the code still went most of the way through the `$http` call, but since the request doesn't end up in the cache that `$httpBackend` expects, there wasn't an obvious way to get the promise chain to actually run.

After some investigation and testing, it turns out that `$rootScope.$digest()` will cause the promises to run, so changing the code to this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
  $compile('<login-page/>')($rootScope);
  $rootScope.$digest();
}));
```

This allowed the `beforeEach` to run, and the directive actually got built, allowing the rest of the test to continue normally.